# Overlaying DIVs with z-index

Tags: css, html, overlay

I am trying to overlay a div over my entire page to show a pop-up. The problem is, it won't overlay over the entire page. Here is an approximation of the code:

```
<div style="z-index:902;">
    <div style="position: fixed; width: 100%; height: 100%; left: 0; top: 0;">
        Overlay
    </div>
    Contents of container 1
</div>
<div style="z-index:902;">
    Contents of container 2
</div>
<div style="z-index:902;">
    Contents of container 3
</div>
```

The overlay div appears on top of container 1, but the contents of container 2 and 3 appear on top of the overlay.

I cannot move my overlay div outside of the container 1, as I am using a CMS (DotNetNuke if that helps).

I have tried setting the z-index of my overlay higher than the containers, but nothing is working.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Do you have to do the popups with a div, or can you do something like a modal window?

Comment: I don't think you are including enough information in this question. The code above would work unless the other div elements are `positioned`. If they are `positioned` then do they need to be? If they do, then you need to set the `z-index` of the div _containing_ the 'overlay' div higher the others - ie `z-index: 903`

Comment: @SomeKittens sometimes the best answer is to try a different approach - I've got rid of the overlay and decided to just open the content in a new window in a plain HTML page.

Comment: @MyHeadHurts I did try setting the overlay z-index higher, but it turns out there was some javascript executing changing the z-index of the other containers.

Comment: @c.cam108 - it wasn't the 'overlay' that you needed to set the z-index on, it was the parent div of the 'overlay'. If you give the parent div an id and add the property `z-index: 903!important` then this would resolve the problem. And in a purely objective sense - the accepted answer (if you are refering to the first part) would never work.

Comment: @MyHeadHurts I can't access that div to edit it unfortunately and it doesn't have an `id` set, only `class` - I am restricted to what is possible using a CMS.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Working [Fiddle Example!](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/H5NB8/)

If you limit the scope of this problem to the code that you've presented, it is working just fine! e.g., On the Fiddle you can see that I placed a background color to the `position:fixed` `div` as to illustrate that the solution is working.

**However**, if you are using `z-index`, is safe to assume that your elements with `z-index` have some `position` applied.

Taking this into consideration, this part:

```
<div style="z-index:902;">
    <div style="position: fixed; width: 100%; height: 100%; left: 0; top: 0;">
        Overlay
    </div>
    Contents of container 1
</div>
```

**cannot work** as an "entire page" overlay since the inner div with `position:fixed` is inside a stacked element that has other stacked elements on the side (siblings), on the same stack position with `z-index:902;`.

See this [Fiddle to illustrate!](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/H5NB8/7/)

If you move the siblings elements to a lower stack position, you can make it work. See this [Fiddle Example!](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/H5NB8/8/)

> **Edited**
>
> This first part of my answer was edited as advised by [My Head Hurts](https://stackoverflow.com/users/681807/my-head-hurts) (see comments), to better explain that the first Fiddle works because the OP placed the question leaving place to guesses! No changes were made to the two solutions presented and approved at this answer!

---

### A solution

would be placing the overlay outside all other divs, but this depends on your goal:

```
<div style="z-index:902;">
    Contents of container 1
</div>
<div style="z-index:902;">
    Contents of container 2
</div>
<div style="z-index:902;">
    Contents of container 3
</div>
<div style="position:fixed; z-index:10000; left:0; top:0; right:0; bottom:0; background:#ccc;">
    Overlay
</div>
```

See this [Fiddle Example!](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/H5NB8/2/)

---

## EDITED

**because of this comment:**

*Yes this would be the ideal answer, and I will accept it as it answers my question as written, but the problem I was facing was from some JavaScript that was dynamically changing the z-index of the other containers that I couldn't control making it impossible to place my div on top of them all.*

**Assuming that you can** place whatever you wish inside `container 1`, and assuming that you are using or can use jQuery, you can do this to solve the problem:

```
<div style="z-index:902;">
  <div class="placeOutside" style="position:fixed; z-index:903; right:0; bottom:0; left:0; top:0; background:#ccc;">
        Overlay
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $('.placeOutside').appendTo('body');
    });
  </script>
  Contents of container 1
</div>
<div style="z-index:902;">
  Contents of container 2
</div>
<div style="z-index:902;">
  Contents of container 3
</div>
```

See this working [Fiddle example!](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/H5NB8/5/)

Comment: Yes this would be the ideal answer, and I will accept it as it answers my question as written, but the problem I was facing was from some Javascript that was dynamically changing the z-index of the other containers that I couldn't control making it impossible to place my div on top of them all.

Comment: Assuming that @c.cam108 is using `positioned` elements then the first part of your answer is incorrect and would not work: http://jsfiddle.net/H5NB8/3/ However, second option is sound but @c.cam108 has already stated that he cannot do that

Comment: @My Head Hurts, as _c.cam108_ said, the first solution solved his issue as written! But your alert did came to my mind, hence the second solution! :) I've edited my answer to place a third option with some Jquery!

Comment: @Zuul That second solution works perfectly! Thanks very much.

Comment: @Zuul - I understand that - but as his problem is written there is no problem. None of the `z-index` values in the divs would have been applied - so the `position: fixed` element would have been drawn on top whether it had a `z-index` or not. For that reason I think you should replace your first solution with an explanation of this - and propose your second two working answers as suggested work arounds.

Comment: @My Head Hurts, Done and done! Glad to see a stackoverflow user motivating my coherence! Many tks!

Answer (score 5):

[`z-index`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#z-index) only works with *positioned elements* (e.g. `position:absolute;`, `position:relative;`, and `position:fixed;`).

> An element is said to be *positioned* if its `position` property has a value other than `static`.
>
> *~ [Visual Formatting Model](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#position-props) of CSS 2.1 Specification*

Comment: Please see [this example](http://www.fiveminuteargument.com/fixed-position-z-index) related to `z-index` and `position:fixed`.

Answer (score 0):

You have given your overlay a width and height of 100%, and since it is a direct descendant of container 1, its width will be calculated to be 100% of the width and height of container 1, thus explaining your problem.

As for a solution, you should probably set the width and height of the overlay to an absolute pixel value for the size of the browser window in JavaScript, prior to showing it.

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for me in firefox:

```
<div style="z-index:1;">
    <div style="position: fixed; width: 100%; height: 100%; left: 0; top: 0; z-index:901;">
        Overlay
    </div>
    Contents of container 1
</div>
<div style="z-index:1;">
    Contents of container 2
</div>
<div style="z-index:1;">
    Contents of container 3
</div>
```

So try it out and see if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution... Imagine two sibling divs. #in-front needs to rest on top of #behind.

```
<div id="behind"></div>
<div id="in-front"></div>
```

Instead of having them be siblings, wrap the first div inside a wrapper and set it's positioning to fixed.

```
<div id="wrapper" style="position:fixed; width:100%; top:0; left:0;">
    <div id="behind"></div>
</div>
<div id="in-front"></div>
```

The #behind div can now position or center itself however it wants. Look at this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nicotr014/xUNv5/13/) for an example. Notice how they work together with no negative margins!

Answer (score 0):

if i mix position relative and absolute width z-index this make no sense:

```
<div style=" Position: fixed ;  z-index:902; width:100%; heigth:100%;background:#F00;">
    Contents of container 2
</div>
<div style="z-index:1; position:relative">
    <div style=" z-index:903; Position: fixed ; left: 0; top: 0;background:#ccc;">
        Overlay
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vLp0am43/